Can we share hotspot programmatically in our flutter application without turning on the device hotspot?
Actually, I am developing an app in which I have to share the connected network with other users on the app with the same name and password, so any user can connect to that network without password.
I am using the WiFiiot package, but this package doesn't support devices that have an Android version older than 12.

no, you cannot do that
